# Pjsip Android: How to use PjCamera class to display user preview

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I have developed Video Call but currently facing one issue of displaying user preview(own preview: Currently I have used **SurfaceView** to display this preview code).

Pjsip library itself using Camera API to sending frames to other user.

There is a **PjCamera** class in Android. Anyone know how to use that class to dispaly your own preview?

======**EDIT**======

```
if (SipManager.currentCall != null &&
                    SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview != null) {
                if (videoPreviewActive) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "$TAG = if")
                    val vidWH = VideoWindowHandle()
                    vidWH.handle?.setWindow(holder.surface)
                    val vidPrevParam = VideoPreviewOpParam()
                    vidPrevParam.window = vidWH
                    try {
                        SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview?.start(vidPrevParam)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        println(e)
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "$TAG = else")
                    try {
                        SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview?.stop()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        println(e)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Aanal Mehta using pjsua_vid_win_info to get (own preview). If wi.is_native == true, you could display wi (own preview).

Comment: Hey @SonPham, I have edited my post. Can you help me with this? If I am doing anything wrong. This code displays preview which is going to shown on the other users display. I am getting king of flip view in my preview screen.

Comment: Hi @Aanal Mehta , have you done video call for mobile?

Comment: Hello @SonPham, it is still in process. Because of some server issues, we are stuck in between.

Comment: Have you ever read "https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPAddressChange" before? I think this is a sulotion for change ip in video call

Comment: @SonPham Thank you for the reference. Will surely look into it. :)